# Send Email with live PDF without sending attachment

Tags: javascript, adobe, livecycle-designer

I am currently working on a live pdf where the user can send local emails which get queued up and sent to server once online. I am using the Adobe Live Cycle Designer. You can send an email using either the built in email button or roll your own with a regular button. It appears that either way you do it an attachment of form data is sent in either xml,pdf,utf.... I want to send only the subject and body. The following code does exactly what I want except I don't want to include the attachment. If anyone has come across this or has any advice it would be much appreciated.

This is the javascript in the click event.

```
            var Mail = "mailto:" + Mailto + "?Subject=" + subject + "&amp;body=" + body;

            event.target.submitForm({  
            cURL: Mail,  
            bEmpty: true,  
            cSubmitAs: "XML"  
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the following will send email without attachment in the click event for a button:

```
    event.target.app.mailMsg({bUI: true, cTo: Mailto, cSubject: subject, cMsg: body});
```